# SplashScreen api with different opener activity

Tags: android, androidx, android-splashscreen

I just now started using the `SplashScreen` api. I have removed my old `SplashActivity` and I am calling `installSplashScreen()` within `MainActivity` before `setContentView`.

The problem is when I was using `SplashActivity` (the old method), I had the chance to make a choice to open the next activity. However, with this new `SplashScreen` api, I couldn't think of any ways to have the same thing. I am already inside the `MainActivity` when the app is open.

The thing is I don't always open `MainActivity` after Splash, I have another activity too that needs to be opened first occasionally right after Splash.

How could I do that? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I found this guide on the Android Developer site: [Keep the splash screen on-screen for longer periods](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#suspend-drawing)

This can be used to check for the condition to load another activity and then load that activity rather than the `MainActivity`

What you can do is, in the `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`'s `onPreDraw` method, you can implement it something like this:

```java
@Override
public boolean onPreDraw() {
    // Check if other activity than MainActivity is to be loaded:
    boolean shouldLoadOtherActivity = /* some condition */;
    if (shouldLoadOtherActivity) {
        // Create intent here to load OtherActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish(); // finish MainActivity
    }
    content.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this); // remove the listener
    return true;
}
```